# Clang, MSVC, GCC disagree about compiling this code with function application in index_sequence

Tags: c++, g++, language-lawyer, c++20, clang++

This code is from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69484179/700825) to another question:

```
template <typename F, std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr auto apply(F f, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
-> std::index_sequence<f(Is)...>
{
    return {};
}
```

gcc fails with

> ```
> <source>:5:29: error: expected parameter pack before '...'
> ```

msvc and clang compile it.

Changing it to this now causes msvc to fail:

```
template <typename F, std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr auto apply(F , std::index_sequence<Is...>)
-> std::index_sequence<F{}(Is)...>
{
    return {};
}
```

> ```
> <source>(5): error C2187: syntax error: '<end Parse>' was unexpected here 
> <source>(5): error C2059: syntax error: '('
> <source>(6): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition 
> <source>(6): error C2059: syntax error: '{'
> <source>(6): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{''
> <source>(6): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
> ```

Is this something vague in C++ standard or just an implementation bug? I see no reason why function calls should not be allowed at this place, same for construction of a `F{}`.

Comment: @xskxzr you need `#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>`

Comment: In case if you want to make it work: https://godbolt.org/z/dz5rdKnsT

Comment: Considering that `f(Is)` is a template argument in a template-argument-list and according to [temp.variadic#5.7](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.variadic#5.7), this should be a valid pack expansion.

Comment: How about clang, btw?

Answer (score 0):

1. This code is from [김선달](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69488653/clang-msvc-gcc-disagree-about-compiling-this-code-with-function-application-in#comment122824376_69488653)'s comment above :

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename F, typename Seq>
struct apply_impl;

template<typename F, std::size_t... Is>
struct apply_impl<F, std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
  private:
    static constexpr auto test(F, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    -> decltype(std::index_sequence< F{}(Is)... > {});
  public:
    using type = decltype(test(F{}, std::index_sequence<Is...>{}));
};

template<typename F, typename Seq>
using apply = typename apply_impl<F, Seq>::type;

constexpr auto f = [](auto x) -> std::size_t { return x*x; };

using res_type = apply<decltype(f), std::index_sequence<0, 1, 2, 3, 4> >;

static_assert(std::is_same<res_type, std::index_sequence<0, 1, 4, 9, 16>>::value);
```

2. And this is from [Mechap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69488653/clang-msvc-gcc-disagree-about-compiling-this-code-with-function-application-in#comment123017550_69488653)'s comment above

   In a `template-argument-list ([temp.arg]);` the pattern is a `template-argument`. From [docs](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.variadic#5.7)

*Note:* Provide solution as an answer instead of a comment.